# Can you auto update the range for a filter in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-filter

I have a Google Sheet document with many rows in it.
I have several filters set up to view different collections of rows.

The problem is, this sheet has new rows automatically added to it several times a day from automated external sources.

So, whenever someone goes to view one of the filters, it is no longer filtering all rows, as the range for the filter does not include the rows added to the sheet since the last set.

Is there a way to have this range automatically update the end of the range to be the "last" row of the sheet?

Comment: filter like `=FILTER()` or like manual overlay filter?

Comment: Ah - asking the real question. I mean a manual overlay - using the menu:  Data - Filter Views

Comment: for manual overlay its not possible to auto update the range

Answer (score 2):

- if your formula is: **`=FILTER(A2:B26, A2:A26 > 5, D2:D26 < 10)`**
- then just don't include the last number of closing range: **`=FILTER(A2:B, A2:A > 5, D2:D < 10)`**

Comment: Thanks - if I can't get the manual overlay to auto update, I might look at creating new sheets that reference the first sheet. One for each filtered view I need.